# ¿Cómo realizo correctamente una resta y división en SQL (Firebird)?

Tags: sql, firebird

Tengo este procedure en Firebird:

```
    create or alter procedure  REP_DOLARES(
        /*Valores de entrada*/
        P_FECHA_DESDE VARCHAR(10),
        P_FECHA_HASTA VARCHAR(10))
    returns (
    /*Valores de retorno*/
        FECHA_EMISION TYPE OF fecha,
        TIPO_DOCUMENTO TYPE OF TIPO_DOCUMENTO,
        NUM_DOC TYPE OF DOCUMENTO,
        TOTAL_CANCELADO_DOLARES TYPE OF MONTOS, /*Lo que cancelo en $*/
        FACTOR_CAMBIO TYPE OF MONTOS,
        MONTO_BS TYPE OF MONTOS /*Valor al cambio*/,
        diferencia TYPE OF MONTOS)
    as
        /*DECLARACIÓN DE VARIABLES*/

        declare variable V_FECHA_DESDE date;
        declare variable V_FECHA_HASTA date;
    begin
    /*FILTRO RANGO DE FECHA*/
    IF (P_FECHA_DESDE='0' OR (P_FECHA_DESDE IS NULL) OR (P_FECHA_DESDE='')) THEN
         V_FECHA_DESDE = CAST('01/01/1900' AS DATE);
    ELSE
         V_FECHA_DESDE  = CAST(:P_FECHA_DESDE AS DATE);

    IF (P_FECHA_HASTA='0' OR (P_FECHA_HASTA IS NULL)OR (P_FECHA_HASTA='')) THEN
         V_FECHA_HASTA = CAST('12/31/3999' AS DATE);
    ELSE
         V_FECHA_HASTA  = CAST(:P_FECHA_HASTA AS DATE);

    /*CICLO DE LA CONSULTA SQL*/
    FOR SELECT  VEN.fecha_emision,
                VEN.tipo_documento,
                VEN.documento,
                VAD.total_monto_pago,
                VAD.factor_cambio,
                VAD.total_monto_pago * VAD.factor_cambio AS MONTO_BS,
                VEN.TOTAL_OPERACION -(VAD.total_monto_pago * VAD.factor_cambio) AS DIFERENCIA_en_bs
        FROM VENTAS VEN
        JOIN VENTAS_AD VAD ON VEN.correlativo = VAD.correlativo
        WHERE ven.fecha_emision BETWEEN :v_fecha_desde AND :v_fecha_hasta
        and vad.pago_me ='T'
        ORDER BY VEN.fecha_emision
        INTO
            :fecha_emision,
            :tipo_documento,
            :num_doc,
            :total_CANCELADO_DOLARES,
            :factor_cambio,
            :monto_bs,
            :diferencia
        DO
            SUSPEND;
    END
```

Todo me funcionaba perfectamente antes de agregar el campo de diferencia, pero ahora una vez que lo agregue me muestra valores exponenciales:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El valor marcado en amarillo debería ser 0, ya que estos campos se llenan a través de esta pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si yo selecciono el botón de $, automáticamente donde dice Total a pagar, se coloca el mismo monto de arriba, sin embargo, esto es editable, en el caso de los que me salen exponencialmente, lo he dejado tal como se muestra, así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el caso que tengo, en total a pagar me sale 2,24$, le doy a pagar los mismos 2,24$ y efectivamente cuando verifico el reporte se me va a exponencial, sin embargo, si coloco 10 unidades me da un total de 22,4 y si marco el botón me dice 22,4 y el reporte me dice 0 (como debería).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo ni idea de porque en el primer caso se me va a exponencial y sabría agradecer su colaboración en la solución de este problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El *problema* está en el tipo de dato del campo subyacente. Las computadoras siempre han tenido ese problema y la explicación es algo larga para darla en una respuesta de StackOverflow.

Lo que tu llamas *salir exponencialmente*, es en realidad el número en notación científica y se utiliza por el hecho de ser números demasiado pequeños o demasiado grandes. `1.81E-12` es `0.00000000000181`, por eso el punto decimal se corre 12 posiciones a la izquierda.

Y esto se debe a que los campos de tu tabla son seguramente de tipo `float` o [`double precision`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formato_en_coma_flotante_de_doble_precisi%C3%B3n), que son tipos de [coma flotante](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coma_flotante) según las especificaciones del IEEE, que van a tener este comportamiento de manera regular al realizar [operaciones aritméticas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic#Representable_numbers,_conversion_and_rounding) con ellos.

La mejor solución es utilizar otro tipo de dato más adecuado para representar la información que manejas y olvidarte de estos detalles.  Por ejemplo, para representar valores monetarios puedes utilizar un tipo `decimal(18,4)`. La precisión de 4 es la más común para almacenar valores contables o relacionados con monedas.

Si el cambio de tipo de dato no es posible, podrías redondear los resultados siempre que hagas operaciones aritméticas, incluida la suma y la resta, por ejemplo, en este caso:

```
select ...
       , round(VEN.TOTAL_OPERACION -(VAD.total_monto_pago * VAD.factor_cambio), 2) AS DIFERENCIA_en_bs
  from ....
```

pero también en otras, como:

```
select round(sum(a.total_operacion), 2)
  from MiTabla
```